# <noscript> stuff </noscript> doesn't work on google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, noscript

I wanted to display a message on the top of my site when the javascript is disabled (just like on SO), but on google chrome is not working

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the current version(s). Reports: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40085 and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36092

Comment: Just an update: The issue has been resolved (and it was a simple mistype error) http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/56064

Comment: There is still the issue (on Windows Chrome versions) that when a page is first loaded, contents of <noscript> displays as html text, instead of being rendered. A second refresh fixes that. So this is still a good way to avoid <noscript> annoyances.

Comment: Is there any other way to achive without refreshing twice ?

Comment: using the chrome development tools(F12) to disable JavaScript did NOT cause the rendering issue but clicking the icon next to the url and disabling JavaScript for the site in site Settings did, where refresh then fixed the issue) Version 42.0.2311.90 m

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks that way.

You can use javascript to hide a 'noscript' message.

Comment: and if there is not going to be js, it is not going to be hidden, you're a genius

Answer (score 2):

Odd. I can repro this in Chrome 4.1.249.1064 (45376)

I had trouble finding it, so here's how:

> you can disable JavaScript on Chrome in Options > Under the Hood > Privacy > Content > Javascript >

Comment: yes, that's how I disabled js in chrome, and SO didn't showed me the content of <noscript> tag, it works with the @zaf solution on my site

Answer (score 1):

I have the current version: Version 30.0.1599.69 m  and can confirm the same or a similar issue.
With javascript disabled, html within the <noscript> tag displays verbatim, not rendered as html html is supposed to format.

Note, this happens one time and one time only: the first time after javascript is disabled. Thereafter, all is well. Refresh the screen and <noscript> works as expected. As such, someone browsing with javascript routinely disabled would not generally experience the quirk.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I've opened Google Chrome with Javascript issuing:

```
 c:\Documents and Settings\grzole\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome -disable-javascript
```

And when visiting some `<noscript>` example found on Internet I can see the message:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSS/Object-Tags/noscriptExample.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSSDemo/noscriptExample.htm

So it looks like it's working. I have Google Chrome 2.0.172.39.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this bug with current Chrome (4.1.249.1064).
It seems not to be a Webkit issue because other webkit-based Browsers support the tag.

Although hiding the text with Javascript may be possible, it is not really an option;
the noscript tag is part oof the w3c standard an so it should be supported by a browser that claims to be standards compliant.